# Information cannot have keys other than those declared on the root type, but it doesn't

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext, ef-fluent-api

Model builder is throwing the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The derived type 'Namespace.myclass' cannot have keys other than those declared on the root type.

**Context**

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {

     modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>((item) =>
     {
            item.HasKey(p => p.MyKey);
     });
 }
```

**MyClass**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        OtherClass = new List<OtherClass>();
    }

    public int MyKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OtherClass> OtherClass { get; set; }
}
```